# factorizing quadratic methods

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, factoring, education

I am wondering if there are any easy ways or variety of ways to show how to factorize quadratics, especially if the variable is given in its inverse form. Or if the highest power coefficient is not 1.

for example, lets consider this:
$1 - 0.4x^{-1} - 0.6x^{-2}$

we can get, $(1 - x^{-1})(1 + 0.6x^{-1})$

my question is really about teaching this. what methods might you suggest and how might you break this down for learners?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Factoring quadratics is a basic topic in high school algebra and the standard texts cover it thoroughly.

Comment: You need just $x^{-1}=u$, I think. Then all the *standard* ways can be apply.

Comment: I think the most procedural way to factorize parabolic equation is to reformulate it into $k[(px+q)^{2}-r^{2}]$, from which the roots are immediately apparent and we can do basic manipulation into $k(px+q+r)(px+q-r)$

Comment: Consider asking questions like this at [Mathematics Educators Stack Exchange](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: agree with all these useful comments. thank u for these. i suppose i am looking for ways to see this instantly or intuitively or a 'short cut'. but having a grounding in basic procedure and practice is perhaps the only way.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the easiest method is to assume
x^-1=t ;
(x^-1)^2=t^2  (Squaring both sides)

and then 1-0.4t-0.6t^2 and then solving it.
OR else the other way can be using the sum of roots and multiplication of roots

like:

alpha+beta=-b/a
and alpha*beta= c/a

or graphical method

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

> Factorize $1 - 0.4x^{-1} - 0.6x^{-2}$

Personally, if a *lucky guess* doesn't present itself in less than a minute, I always resort to *brute force*, which is reasonably quick.

First, I will re-express the function as

$$\frac{1}{x^2} \times f(x) ~: ~f(x) = x^2 - 0.4x - 0.6.$$

Then, I will apply brute force against $~f(x).~$  Then, I will re-apply the factor $~\dfrac{1}{x}~$ to each of the resulting factors.

$$f(x) = 0 \iff x = \frac{1}{2} \left[ ~0.4 \pm \sqrt{0.16 + (4 \times 0.6)} ~\right] \iff $$

$$x = \frac{0.4 \pm \sqrt{2.56}}{2} = 0.2 \pm 0.8 \iff $$

$$x = \frac{2 \pm 8}{10}.$$

Therefore,

$$f(x) ~\text{factors to}~ 
\left( ~x - \frac{2 + 8}{10} ~\right) 
\times \left( ~x - \frac{2 - 8}{10} ~\right) $$

$$= ~(x-1) \times \left(x + \frac{3}{5}\right) \implies $$

$$\frac{1}{x^2} ~f(x) ~\text{factors to}~ 
\left( ~1 - \frac{1}{x} ~\right) 
\times \left( ~1 + \frac{3}{5x} ~\right). $$

Comment: The method is correct, however the evaluation is incorrect, please check again.

Comment: @Dstarred Answer edited.